# WPF: Adding a Command to each MenuItem in a data-bound dynamic Menu

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, menuitem

How can I add a command to each item in a data-bound menu? Basically, I have something like this:

```
     <MenuItem Header="View" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" />
```

For each item in the menu, I need to give it a Command based on its DataContext. I can't use the ItemTemplate since the template is inside the generated MenuItem container. Oh, and the commands need to have input gestures, so they need to be generated before the menu is opened.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe I should add/remove the items in code-behind?

Comment: Eh can you give a better example? I don't fully understand what do you want exactly

Comment: Can you try to use CommandParameter property and bind each menuitem to the same command. So you can use implement the executed event depending on the different parameters.

Comment: @Howard - That's cleaner than the answer I accepted, but how to set the command parameters?

Comment: CommandParameter is a property in MenuItem. You can set fix parameter and also you can binding to your dynamic parameters. In the executed event, you can access the parameter you set in this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that MenuItem (and Menu) are just ItemsControls. This means that you can bind a collection of anything to it. In other words you can bind it to a collection of whatever has the ICommand on it (aka, your viewmodel).

But we dont want that, we want MenuItems right? So what you can do is make the collection you're binding to a collection of MenuItems that you create behind the scenes.

However we dont really want to have controls instanciated in the codebehind if we can help it. It leads to poor testability and is genereally clunky.

So what we can do instead is bind to a collection of your buisness objects but use a [*custom TypeConverter*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx) to convert that list into a list of MenuItems that are correctly bound to each object

Whats really nice about this approach is that it works no matter how deep you menu structure is. The Typeconverter can walk though your viewmodel and recursivly add new bindings that in turn use the same type converter

Another option is to create a DataTemplate for your menu item viewmodel that in turn contains a MenuItem, but im not entirely sure how to handle gestures using that approach. it might be possible though and that approach is also recursive.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks! I've been using ValueConverters so much I totally forgot about type converters... Yeah, I tried the DataTemplate with MenuItem approach, but that looked weird since it was a menu item inside a menu item.

Comment: Yeah, i remeber reading somewhere that that could be a problem.. You might already know about this but as a reference, here's the HowTo page for create bindings in code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx